# Command Prompt on Windows 8 not recognizing any commands

Tags: command-line, cmd, windows-8

Here's a screenshot of the command prompt message:
[image: screenshot]

It says "'$' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

I looked up how to fix it, then changed the PATH in computer properties and updated my Java like they said, but it's still not fixed.

Comment: Not recognising *any* commands? Try `echo test`, does it work? Also, what command is '$' supposed to be?

Comment: `echo test` does work. I'm trying to follow this documentation https://github.com/shakyShane/jekyll-gulp-sass-browser-sync using this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nY4kQssg3lw&t=408s

Comment: paste the message as text, some users cannot open pictures

Comment: The "$" signifies the prompt, specifically for a normal user without elevated privileges. That tutorial is not for windows. In the comments of the video there's a tutorial on how to get it working on a windows PC.

Comment: @Regejok Either way I need my command prompt to work.

Comment: @WhatsThePoint I did.

Comment: Have you installed ruby for Windows? [Have a look at this site.](https://rubyinstaller.org/)

Comment: @Regejok Is that going to fix my problem? Because that'd be pretty awesome.

Comment: `gem` (RubyGems) is a packet manager for ruby. Without ruby installed, you don't have gem. Once you get that to work, you can execute the commands.

Comment: @Regejok Alright. I'll try that. Thank you. :)

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Is `gem` the name of a program you're trying to run? Because you can just type `gem install jekyll` without the $. The gem executable would have to be in a folder that's present in the PATH variable.

Comment: If I type 'gem install jekyll' it tells me "'gem'  is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: @EmilyGray Have you made sure gem is located in either a directory contained in %path% or in the working directory?

Comment: @Regejok I'm following a tutorial. It doesn't say anything about locating gem in my directory. I don't see anything titled gem in my C://WINDOWS/System32 folder.